# Variable does not exist when it does exists

Tags: ajax

I'm using an AJAX request to get answers from an API. This is my AJAX code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#search-client').keyup(function (){
                let client = $('#search-client').val();
                console.log(client);
                if( client != "" && typeof client !== 'undefined'){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '{{ path('sellsy_client', {clientName: client}) }}',
                        data: 'clientName=' + encodeURIComponent(client),
                        success: function (data){
                            if (data != ""){
                                $('#result-search').append(data);
                            }else{
                                document.getElementById('result-search').innerHTML = "<div>Aucun résultat</div>";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

I have an error

```
Variable "client" does not exist.
```

on `url: '{{ path('sellsy_client', {clientName: client}) }}'` But the thing is, it does exist. If i remove the AJAX part, the console log displays client. And I tried accessing the var client if it isn't undefined and isn't "" but I still have the same error. What's the problem?

Comment: something seems off with the quotations. Did you try replacing `'{{path ...}}'` with `"{{path ...}}"` ?

Comment: Same error if I change the quotations, or even remove them.

Comment: I meant that you should alternate between single and double quotes if you have them nested. that's all I could think of. I'm not really familiar with url pointing to anything other than filename or filename.ext type of requests.

Comment: Where about is the error thrown? On the `if` statement?

Comment: When removing the param `{clientName: client}` in the URL it works. The error seems to be coming from this but I don't see what's wrong in the way I wrote the url